# BIOS corruption failure

Tags: windows-7, laptop, bios, laptop-repair, hp-laptop

I have an HP laptop g42-415dx and when i start it up the Caps lock light blinks twice and then I get a blank screen. The HP website states that 2 blinks means BIOS corruption.

At the beginning it was giving me 1 blink which meant CPU failure so i have replaced the CPU and now it is giving me 2 blinks. I tried removing memory, CD, hard drive, removing the battery, holding the power button for 1 minute and then turning it on. I also tried pressing windows and B key and turning it on for a bios backup but none of them are working, I just have a blank screen and that's it. What else could I try?

ADD:
I want to add that before this problem I had an issue which was giving me a massage at startup
"System Board OOA Product Information Not Valid" but i just clicked okay and it contuniued to Windows. However, after couple of minutes it would crash and give me a different blue screen of deaths.

Comment: Are you sure you have replaced the CPU correctly?

Comment: yes, i am pretty sure, i don't even know why it was giving me a cpu error at the beginning, i didn't noticed any flaws in the old cpu, by i changed it anyways.

Answer (score 0):

If the BIOS is truly corrupted, than I don't believe there's any hop unless your motherboard has an emergency restore feature or the BIOS is socket loaded and can be replaced. Normally, this means the motherboard must be replaced or you're really good at soldering and can replace the chip. However, before you go buying new things yet, make absolutely certain that everything is seated properly and snug. If there are any other board indicator lights or a speaker, pay attention to them because board speakers and lights beep/blink in special patterns as to diagnose BIOS problems.

Good luck to you!